# Update array state from one component to another react hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, api

I am trying a MERN blog website project. Currently, I am facing a problem when updating the comment on a post. I am editing the comment from another component but I am unable to update the state after updating the comment. Anyone to help me out thanks.

Client Code for EditComment component:

```
    import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import Input from '../components/Input';
import Axios from 'axios';

export const EditComment = (props) => {
    const [commentBody, setComment] = useState(props.comment.commentBody);
    console.log(props.comment._id)
    const [commentState, setCommentState] = useState([props.cmtState]);


    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { value, name } = event.target
        setComment(value)
    }

    console.log(commentBody)

    const handleCommentEdit = async (postid, commentid) => {
        try {
            const res = await Axios.patch(`/api/posts/${postid}/comments/${commentid}`,JSON.stringify({commentBody}), {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +localStorage.getItem('token')
                }
            })
            setCommentState(prevValue => {
                return [...prevValue, res.data.info]
            });
            console.log(res)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log( error.response.request );
        }
    }

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <i 
                data-toggle="modal" data-target={`#exampleModal${props.comment._id}`}
                className="fa fa-pencil ml-3" 
                style={{color: "blue", cursor: 'pointer'}}></i>
            <div 
                className="modal fade" 
                id={`exampleModal${props.comment._id}`} 
                tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" 
                aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
                aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    <h5 
                        className="modal-title" 
                        id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        className="close" 
                        data-dismiss="modal" 
                        aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <Input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="commentBody" 
                        value={commentBody} 
                        onChange={ handleChange } 
                        className="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        className="btn btn-secondary" 
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        onClick={() => handleCommentEdit(props.postid, props.comment._id)}
                        data-dismiss="modal"
                        className="btn btn-warning">Save changes</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Client code for displaying comment (Where it need to show the update state):

```
 const [commentBody, setComment] = useState('');
    const [commentState, setCommentState] = useState([]);
 <h6>Comments</h6>
                {
                    commentState.length > 0 ? commentState.map((comment, index) => {
                        return(
                            <div key={index} className="mb-2">
                                <span className="mr-2">{comment.commentBody}</span>
                                <span className="mr-2 text-primary"><em>-{comment.commentBy.name}</em></span>
                                <span className="text-secondary"><em>{formatDate(comment.createdAt)}</em></span>
                                {
                                    authContext.userState.user && authContext.userState.user._id === comment.commentBy._id &&
                                    <Fragment>
                                        <EditComment cmtState={commentState} comment={comment} postid={postid}/>
                                        <i 
                                            className="fa fa-trash ml-3" 
                                            onClick={() => handleCommentDelete(postid, comment._id)}  
                                            style={{color: "red", cursor: 'pointer'}}></i>
                                    </Fragment>
                                }
                                
                            </div>
                        )
                        
                    }) :""  
                }
```

Comment: Any errors you see? Also if possible can you share the sandbox link of the code. Do you want to update the parent component state when the edit comment happens?

Comment: No errors. But it doesn't update the state of DisplayPost(where all comment is showed) when I edit the comment from the EditComment component. Yes, sure.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-star-qgi2w @HarmandeepSinghKalsi

Comment: You seem to have uploaded entire project :) it's supposed to be only minimal code to show how to replicate. Anyway, how to login & replicate afterwards?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Sorry but #Harmandeep want to see the code.

Comment: @tmhao2005 I will keep my project as open-sourced that's why I agreed. :)

Comment: I can support you if you show me how to login & replicate anyway

Comment: That would be great. By login and replicate you mean access to my code? @tmhao2005

Comment: I seems to see some glitches in your code. Basically, you just invoke the callback which is placed on the parent as you have just updated your comment. Then you just simply update your array at specific index. Anyway as I see the login screen on your codesanbox.

Comment: @tmhao2005 I think I should do it in a manual way calling the allComments API when made the edit action. The brain is ticking me like this right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219239/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-jakaria-ridoy).

Comment: Obviously you can do that way which can be called online way. But if you want to optimize your code by not calling too many requests, you can do offline update like this. If you still wan to resolve this offline way, I can give you a suggestion snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure since the React component to show the comments is not fully visible, but it looks like you are not updating the `commentState` at any time. It is and remains empty it seems to  me.

Comment: In the EditComment components, I updated it like `setCommentState(prevValue => {
                return [...prevValue, res.data.info]
            });`
where I pass the commentstate from the DisplayPost (here all comments are shown). But, that's not working. :(

Comment: It looks like you have a main component that contains the `Comments`element and under it is the `EditComment` component. You update the `commentState` in `EditComment`, but this does not mean it will be automatically updated in the parent component. The `commentState`should be updated in the parent component, where you want to show it, and passed to `EditComponent`as props.

Comment: I think you should have the click handling function in the parent component, which updates the `commentState` in it, and pass it to `EditComment` as props. Then in `EditComment`you can call it and pass the new comment. This way the new comment is saved by the parent component, and it also updates the `commentState`.

Comment: Yes, it has. But, I am really unsure about how to do that. Because, as you can see, I also passed the CommentState from parent (DisplayComponent) to EditComment component as props. Can we give me some way how to do that?

Comment: Okay, let me try it out. Thanks for the hint.